# cannot convert string to char* in getstr()

Tags: c++, string, char

So I'm just trying to write an empty string to a `char [80]` and I get the error "cannot convert string to char* in getstr()"? (I get this in general when writing a string to a `char` array like `char[80] = "hello world"`.)

This includes a lot of ncurses stuff btw. Didn't include other functions.

```
int main(){
    std::string message;

    //...

    for(;;){
        wrefresh(chatWin);
        message = "hello world";

        getstr(message);
        if(message != ""){
            displayMessage(message, displayLine, displayWin);
            wmove(chatWin, 1, 7);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to get the input from the user from the function but it throws the error "cannot convert string to char* in getstr()". `getstr` is from ncurses. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use `char message[80];`, instead use `std::string message;`.

Comment: You cannot assign a string literal to a `char` array. C++ does not work this way. If your intent is to write modern C++ code, use `std::string`. If your intent is to write old-style C code, use `strcpy()`.

Comment: @Versalys show us how you tried to use `std::string`.

Comment: To set `message` to an empty string do `message[0] = 0;`

Comment: sorry, when I was trying to edit my code I created a string array lol. fixed that. But now i run into the error with getstr(message) because it cant convert the string to a char*.

Comment: By changing your question to use `std::string message` instead of `char message[80]`, now you have a completely new question.  Your `getstr` is expecting a `char*`, not a `std::string`.   Although `std::string` is a excellent idea, it's a bigger change to make use of it; you can't just drop-in replace the declaration of `message` and not adjust all the usages.  You should probably put it back, lest this question get derailed.

Comment: @Wyck is there anyway to cast a string to a char* for the function or not?

Comment: @Versalys See my answer, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037474/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-stdstring-to-a-function-that-accepts-a-char-and-ch)

Comment: Another effect of changing your question's code to use `std::string` instead of `char [80]` is that the text of your question no longer makes sense when it mentions `char [80]`. In its current hybrid form (even before my edit), the question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you had written something like this:

```
int main() {
   char message[80];
   message = "";
}
```

This will yield the error:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [1]' to 'char [80]'

To set `message` to an empty string you can do it the idiomatic way of copying an empty string into the `message` array like this:

```
strcpy(message, "");
```

or simply place a null terminating character at the beginning of the array like this:

```
message[0] = 0;
```

---

Can't, with good conscience, write this post without mentioning that `std::string` is a good idea.  But it may be inconvenient to port all your existing code that uses a char array to the technique of using a `std::string`.  For example, `getstr` likely expects a `char*` not a `std::string`.  Instead you'll need to interoperate between char arrays and `std::string` by way of a `std::vector<char>`.  I think it's out of scope to answer exactly how in this answer.

```
#include <string>
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
   std::string message;
   message = ""; // This works.
   getstr(message); // This doesn't. (assuming `getstr` from curses.h)
}
```

See also [Is there any way to pass a std::string to a function that accepts a char* and changes its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037474/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-stdstring-to-a-function-that-accepts-a-char-and-ch)

Comment: Never use `strcpy` or similar functions when you don't know the size of source strings; it can lead to undefined behaviour and security vulnerabilities. Use `strncpy` (and `getnstr`) instead.

Comment: By the way, since C++17 the underlying buffer accessed by `std::string::data()` is no longer `const`, so you can use it directly.

Comment: @Erbureth, your advice to write the `getnstr` data `to std::string::data()` without knowing the destination size is also dangerous. You didn't explain how to ensure there are enough bytes at `data()` for the `getnstr` to be successful (presumably at least 80 are desired). You didn't explain how `getnstr` would set the length of the `std::string` if it writes fewer chars than the original size of the string. Something ugly like `message.erase(std::find(message.begin(), message.end(), '\0'), message.end());` after the `getnstr` would be required I think. I don't recommend your advice as written.

Comment: This is not the answer, but comment to your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Wyck for helping me with my problem, even if I didn't know what in the holy hell I was doing, I got it running after a couple hours. It just cost me my stackoverflow reputation XD

Comment: You can use `std::string::resize()` to tell a given string how many characters it should have, @Wyck.  In this case, if used with `getnstr()`, you would want it to have a size of at least `n`.